# Installed the game, but unable to play

Tags: software-installation, games

I'm totally new with Ubuntu (18.04). I have installed GOG game with .sh extension via terminal. When I starting the game, application window opens (not in full window) and as soon as I point cursos on game window, it starts lagging extremly hard.

note: I also noticed that game installation ends with the following lines:
"trying mojosetup in bin/linux/x86_64
USING 
"
Game which was installed via Steam (not via terminal) works fine. I just getting acquainted with ubuntu 18.04 and want to know, why it happens and what is wrong.

Also, how to make app in fullscreen?

Thank you!